# Typescript - Get typeof function arguments

Tags: typescript, redux

Is it possible to get the type of a function's arguments with TypeScript?

I have a function that returns another function that returns a promise:

```
type login = (params: LoginParams) => dispatched
type dispatched = (dispatch: Dispatch) => Promise<any>
```

I would like to create a generic type that takes function as a param and creates a new function type. For example:

```
GenericFunctionType<login>
```

Would create the following type:

```
(LoginParams) => Promise<any>
```

In short GenericFunctionType creates a function type with the arguments of the initial function (login) and return value of the returned function (dispatched).

---

I want this because I am using Redux. Here is my use case:

```
//Action Creator
export type login = (params: LoginParams) => ThunkAction<Promise<any>>;

export const login: login = params => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: LOGIN });

  const promise = httpClient.post('/auth/sign_in', params);

  ...stuff

  return promise;
};
```

My Login component is connected like so:

```
interface LoginProps {
  login: ???
}

class Login extends React.component<LoginProps, {}> {...}

connect(null, {login})(Login)
```

I'm trying to find a reusable way of typing action creators that have been wrapped in dispatch (which is what `connect` does).

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Types are not data and generic types are not functions that return other types, nor are they objects containing their parameters. It seems like you're actually trying to export two types. I would recommend wrapping your login function in a module that exports your login function and two types, Params (loginParams) and Result (Promise<any>).

Answer (score 10):

Use [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) type from default library

---

**Old answer**

You can use [tsargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsargs) package from npm for this.

Your case:

```
import { Arg1 } from 'tsargs';

type GenericFunctionType<F extends Function> = (params: Arg1<F>) => Promise<any>;
```

Examples with tsargs:

```
import { Arg2, Args2off1, ArgsN } from 'tsargs';

function foo(a: boolean, b: number, c: string) {}

// pick specific argument
const secondArg: Arg2<typeof foo> = 123;

// pick 2 arguments skipping first
const argsBC: Args2off1<typeof foo> = [ 123, 'Hello' ];

// pick all arguments
const argsABC: ArgsN<typeof foo> = [ true, 123, 'Hello' ];
```

Answer (score 9):

For TypeScript 3.0

We can get function arguments type as tuple types like below

```js
type ArgsType<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any ? U : never;
```

Comment: And the answer to the question is:
`type GenericFunctionType<T, R = any> = T extends (...args: infer U) => any ? (...args: U) => Promise<R> : never;`